# How to create a script to export AWS security groups with rules in table structured format (CSV or TSV)

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli

I want to create a script to export AWS security groups with rules in table structured format (CSV or TSV)

I require the following Values:

- SecurityGroups

  - **GroupName**
  - **GroupId**
  - **IpPermissions/IpPermissionsEgress**

    - **FromPort**
    - **ToPort**
    - **IpProtocol**
    - IpRanges

      - **CidrIp**
      - **Description**
      - UserIdGroupPairs

        - **GroupId**
        - **Description**

e.g.,

| GroupName | GroupId | IpPermissions/IpPermissionsEgress | FromPort | ToPort | IpProtocol | CidrIp | Description | GroupId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| default | 123456789 | IpPermissions/IpPermissionsEgress | 123 | 123 | xxx | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/x | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx | sg-123456789 |

As far I have tried with

**AWS CLI command:**

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query \
'SecurityGroups[*].{"01_GroupName":GroupName, "02_GroupId":GroupId,
"03_FromPort":IpPermissions[0].FromPort,
"04_ToPort":IpPermissions[0].ToPort,
"05_Protocol":IpPermissions[0].IpProtocol,
"06_RuleGroupId":IpPermissions[0].UserIdGroupPairs[0].GroupId,
"07_RuleCidr":IpPermissions[0].IpRanges[0].CidrIp,
"08_Justification":IpPermissions[0].UserIdGroupPairs[0].Description}' \
--output text  > instances.tsv
```

The results of the AWS CLI:
| default | sg-123456789 |  443 |   443 |   tcp |   None |  0.0.0.0/0 | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |

Problems with results of the AWS CLI:

- Most importantly, it only outputs the first security group and the first security rule (no recursive), Each security group has many security rules (one to many)
- How to put together IpPermissions and IpPermissionsEgress (Inbound/Outbound rules) in a single query?
- How to put the type of security rule in the column. E.g. is this IpPermissions(Inbound)/IpPermissionsEgress(Outbound rules)?
- Added labels in the query, even though it doesn't show as column labels.

**Secondly, with Boto3 + Pandas**

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)

ec2_client = boto3.client("ec2")
paginator = ec2_client.get_paginator("describe_security_groups")
result = []

try:
    response_iterator = paginator.paginate()
    for page in response_iterator:
        each_page = page.get("SecurityGroups")
        each_sg = pd.json_normalize(
            each_page, "IpPermissions", ["GroupName", "GroupId"]
        )
        each_df = pd.json_normalize(
            each_page, record_path=["IpPermissions", "IpRanges"], meta=["GroupId"]
        )

        # reorder columns
        each_sg = each_sg[
            [
                "GroupId",
                "FromPort",
                "ToPort",
                "IpProtocol",
                "GroupName",
                "UserIdGroupPairs",
            ]
        ]
        each_sg.to_csv("multiplelevel_normalized_review_data-sg.csv", index=False)
        each_df.to_csv("multiplelevel_normalized_review_data-df.csv", index=False)
        result = pd.merge(each_sg, each_df)
        result.to_csv("multiplelevel_normalized_review_data-result.csv", index=False)

except ClientError as e:
    print(e)
```

The results of the Boto3 + Pandas:

| GroupId | FromPort | ToPort | IpProtocol | GroupName | IpProtocol | UserIdGroupPairs | CidrIp | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sg-123456789 | 443 | 443 | tcp | default | 0.0.0.0/0 | [{'Description': 'xxx', 'GroupId': 'sg-123456789', 'UserId': '123456789'}, {'Description': 'xxx', 'GroupId': 'sg-123456789', 'UserId': '123456789'}}] | 0.0.0.0/0 | xxxxxxxxxxx |

Problems with results of the Boto3 + Pandas:

- The script is only working for IpPermissions (Inbound) rules.
- The numbers of records are different in each CSV file and a few security groups missing in the final - merge CSV file:
  -- multiplelevel_normalized_review_data-sg.csv 122
  -- multiplelevel_normalized_review_data-df.csv 88
  -- multiplelevel_normalized_review_data-result.csv 237
- The script doesn't flatten the nested list UserIdGroupPairs .
- How to put the type of security rule in the column. E.g. is this IpPermissions(Inbound)/IpPermissionsEgress(Outbound rules)?

Comment: Does it work? What is your specific issue/question? Please note that much of the data you seek is hierarchical, which does not make it easy to store in a 'flat' structure such as a CSV file. For example, how would it store multiple IpRanges or multiple IpPermissions?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein
No, it doesn't work.
The requirement is to make the report list of security groups and rules out of a multi-level nested list.

Comment: So what doesn't work? Is it successfully retrieving the information from AWS? Are there any error messages? Is the problem simply a matter of how to display the information? Can you describe your _specific_ issue?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you for helping me to clarify the issue.
Yes, it's successfully retrieving the information from AWS, but the result is not as expected, I've updated the issue with results and problems.